# How to perform a conditional sort in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm performing a binary classification and I want to manually review cases where the model either made an incorrect guess or it was correct but with low confidence. I want the most confident incorrect predictions to appear first, followed by less confident predictions, followed by correct predictions sorted from least to most confident. I want to manually check these examples to see if there's a pattern to the types of examples where the model needs help. My real project involves images created using Stable Diffusion, so I can create more targeted training examples if I see patterns.

Here's a simplified example of my data.

```
import polars as pl

pl.DataFrame({"name":["Alice", "Bob", "Caroline", "Dutch", "Emily", "Frank", "Gerald", "Henry", "Isabelle", "Jack"],
    "truth":[1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0],
              "prediction": [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0],
              "confidence": [0.343474,0.298461,0.420634,0.125515,0.772971,0.646964,0.833705,0.837181,0.790773,0.144983]}).with_columns(
    (1*(pl.col("truth") == pl.col("prediction"))).alias("correct_prediction")
)
```

Emily should appear first because she's the highest-confidence incorrect classification. After the other wrong predictions, Dutch should appear next because he has the lowest-confidence correct guess.

| name | truth | prediction | confidence | correct_prediction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emily | 1 | 0 | 0.772971 | 0 |
| Frank | 0 | 1 | 0.646964 | 0 |
| Bob | 0 | 1 | 0.298461 | 0 |
| Dutch | 0 | 0 | 0.125515 | 1 |
| Jack | 0 | 0 | 0.144983 | 1 |
| Alice | 1 | 1 | 0.343474 | 1 |
| Caroline | 1 | 1 | 0.420634 | 1 |
| Isabelle | 1 | 1 | 0.790773 | 1 |
| Gerald | 0 | 0 | 0.833705 | 1 |
| Henry | 1 | 1 | 0.837181 | 1 |

I'm moving from Pandas to Polars and can't figure out how to perform this sort. According to [the documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.sort.html), you can use an expression with `sort()`, but it's not clear how I can include an if statement in the expression. I'd also be open to calculating a new sort column and then performing a simple `sort()` on that, if there's some formula that would do what I want.

I know I could split the DataFrame into `correct_predictions` and `incorrect_predictions`, use different sorting logic on each, and then `concat()` them back together. I'm looking for something more elegant and less messy.

Comment: You'll need to give us the code with the generated values. As the example uses random numbers it's not reproducible. Including the full expected output would also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made your example with random numbers and then listed off the names as though they're fixed so therefore I don't have the same order as you're saying but from the description I believe this is right.

```
df.sort([
    (good_pred:=pl.col('truth').eq(pl.col('prediction'))),
    (good_pred-1)*pl.col('confidence'),
    pl.col('confidence')
])
shape: (10, 5)
┌──────────┬───────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ name     ┆ truth ┆ prediction ┆ confidence ┆ correct_prediction │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---                │
│ str      ┆ i64   ┆ i64        ┆ f64        ┆ i32                │
╞══════════╪═══════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ Bob      ┆ 0     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.359116   ┆ 0                  │
│ Emily    ┆ 1     ┆ 0          ┆ 0.088916   ┆ 0                  │
│ Frank    ┆ 0     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.03878    ┆ 0                  │
│ Alice    ┆ 1     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.100859   ┆ 1                  │
│ Jack     ┆ 0     ┆ 0          ┆ 0.175356   ┆ 1                  │
│ Henry    ┆ 1     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.307952   ┆ 1                  │
│ Gerald   ┆ 0     ┆ 0          ┆ 0.376189   ┆ 1                  │
│ Isabelle ┆ 1     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.586589   ┆ 1                  │
│ Dutch    ┆ 0     ┆ 0          ┆ 0.701469   ┆ 1                  │
│ Caroline ┆ 1     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.989262   ┆ 1                  │
└──────────┴───────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

The first sort expression checks if truth == prediction. When it doesn't then it returns false which appears first in the sort.

In the second sort expression, I'm relying on bools being converted to 0/1. Since the first results you want to see are false, that's a 0. I subtract 1 from that and multiply it by the confidence. Since the result of that is either the negative of the confidence or zero it means that you get confidence in descending order for wrong predictions without interfering with correct prediction order.

The last sort expression is just the confidence as-is which will apply to the rows where truth==prediction.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, it works in the demo example and on my full-scale dataset. IMO this is a better demonstration of the power of using an expression in sort() than anything in the documentation. (I fixed the error in my question at the same time you posted your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

As for how to write an "if-statement" in Polars, you can use [`when/then/otherwise`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/expressions/functions/#conditionals)

```py
df.sort(
   pl.when(pl.col("correct_prediction") == 0)
     .then(-pl.col("confidence"))
     .otherwise(pl.col("confidence"))
)
```

```py
shape: (10, 5)
┌──────────┬───────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ name     ┆ truth ┆ prediction ┆ confidence ┆ correct_prediction │
│ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---                │
│ str      ┆ i64   ┆ i64        ┆ f64        ┆ i32                │
╞══════════╪═══════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ Emily    ┆ 1     ┆ 0          ┆ 0.772971   ┆ 0                  │
│ Frank    ┆ 0     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.646964   ┆ 0                  │
│ Bob      ┆ 0     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.298461   ┆ 0                  │
│ Dutch    ┆ 0     ┆ 0          ┆ 0.125515   ┆ 1                  │
│ Jack     ┆ 0     ┆ 0          ┆ 0.144983   ┆ 1                  │
│ Alice    ┆ 1     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.343474   ┆ 1                  │
│ Caroline ┆ 1     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.420634   ┆ 1                  │
│ Isabelle ┆ 1     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.790773   ┆ 1                  │
│ Gerald   ┆ 0     ┆ 0          ┆ 0.833705   ┆ 1                  │
│ Henry    ┆ 1     ┆ 1          ┆ 0.837181   ┆ 1                  │
└──────────┴───────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────────────┘
```